# How to set input box id from data in knockout loop

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to set the `id` of an `input` box which am getting in for loop using knockout. How do I set this?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: testData">
    <span class="cld" data-bind="text:flid"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hid_freq_{flid}" name="hid_freq_{flid}">
 </div>
```

In the above code i am getting flid as data in a `span` I want to use that same data as an id for an `input` box, so please let me know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: In what lang u want to get the flid tag? jquery?

Comment: can you please make question more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) to set any attributes like `id` or `name`

```
<span class="cld" data-bind="text:flid"/>
<input type="hidden" 
   data-bind="attr: { id: 'hid_freq_' + flid(), name: 'hid_freq_' + flid() }">
```

Note: you only need to write `flid()` only if your flid property is a `ko.observable` otherwise you just need `'hid_freq_' + flid`.